# Nativescript Offline Data

Tags: sql, database, nativescript

I'm quite new to NativeScript so I'm after some advice.

I've been looking at different back-end database solutions for the data.  I've looked at firebase and while it does what it says on the tin I've come from am SQL relationship database background historically.

I've had a look and see that kinvey can connect to azure database (haven't tested this as yet)

I've looked at the azure database plugin but at present that doesn't support offline data.

Just wondering what other people have tried and recommend/stay away from.

Answer (score 0):

Your use plugin nativescript-sqlite.